# How to filter articles by jcfields (Custom Fields)?

Tags: custom-field

i'm trying to filter articles by custom fields.
In Wordpress it's quite easy to do, but i'm blocked now.

Here's what i would imagine right to do, but it's not:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');

// Get an instance of the generic articles model
$model = JModel::getInstance('Articles');

// Set application parameters in model
$app       = JFactory::getApplication();
$appParams = $app->getParams();

$model->setState('params', $appParams);

// Tri
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $catid);

// Isn't it possible??
$model->setState('filter.jcfields.test', "TEST");


// Retrives items
$items = $model->getItems();

dump($items);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

May be this solution will answer to your question: [JL Content Fields Filter](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/jl-content-fields-filter/).

Comment: Interesting extension thanks for sharing. Just for the sake of completeness consider to add more details in your answer about how this extension may help the OP - otherwise this answer should be converted to a comment.

Comment: Interresting,  but does not Joomla offers a way to do it without installing a tierce plugin or module?

Answer (score 2):

Joomla! doesn't provide this function and it's quite a shame. There is no filter, nor ordering by default. The only way to do that correctly is to use http://easylayouts.net/ extention. It provides ordering and filtering on menu items AND a great com_content override system. There is some place for improvment, but still it solves a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Update: If you are looking for a content filtering solution for Joomla 4, you can try [JFilters](https://blue-coder.com/jfilters)

Among others, you can filter your articles by Custom Fields, Categories and Tags. Can be combined with the Joomla's Smart Search and is SEO friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine it to be done by creating a search plugin that reads out the desired custom fields and their values and performs a filter query instead of a search on the listed content. This is just a thought though, I haven't checked the search plugin code to be sure.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing. Please take our [tour].